# What character can be used instead of / to separate URL path?

Tags: url, rfc3986, ietf

In a URL, according to [this syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Generic_syntax), I want to use a different delimiter for separating path in a URL.

For example:

In this URL `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Generic_syntax`, I want to separate `wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier` with a symbol other than `/`, but I want to make sure it does not break the [URL syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) formalized by **IETF**.

I am only concerned about the path, how do I separate its components like `wiki` and `Uniform_Resource_Identifier`

Comment: Why do you want to use another separator?

Comment: Also, what makes you think that there **can** be another separator than the slash? Paragraph 3.3 does not list any other character to seperate path segments

Comment: I am trying to store the path and `/` is not allowed..

Comment: Then please share more details. Nobody can guess **how** you want to store that, and **why** the common identifier for seperating path segments should not be allowed

Comment: I am trying to use Firebase which cannot use `/` for collection ID name. Check this https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#collections_documents_and_fields.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the URL encoding for / `%2F`

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki%2FUniform_Resource_Identifier#Generic_syntax
```

Comment: That escaped character does not fulfill the same purpose

Comment: That works, but the more common way is the other way round: Use slashes as delimiters and put `%2f` in the names that have "actual" slashes in them. Like `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC%2fDC`. (Wikipedia chose to use anything after the `wiki/` as a native slash, which is fine too as long as there's no nesting of pages).

Answer (score 0):

As far as your application's use of URIs is concerned, the `/` is barely more special than any other character, with two weak exceptions:

- Using any character defined as delimiter ([gen-delims and sub-delims in RFC3986](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-2.2)) has, when used as your separator, the upside that you can optionally escape it. That means you can have a `/` in your name even if you separate your components by a slash, as in `wiki/AC%2FDC` (which has a component `AC/DC` after your application does the splitting), but just the same you can separate your components with a `;` and still have `wiki;Steins%3bGate` for `Steins;Gate`.
- Only when using relative references, then `/` are special in that you can do `../../` on slashes but not with any other delimiter. (And this is the only place where the path segments really matter).

So really, pick whichever you like for your application; the client should (at least under HATEOAS, or really general REST, assumptions) not put too much meaning to the components anyway.